# How to handle realign of components in runtime after screen resize delphi

Tags: delphi, resize, firemonkey, firedac

I searched a lot in google to get a clearer info on how I could solve my current issue, but I got scalability of components as the best answer, that's... not yet my issue.

So, long story short: I want to realign components on my form after the user resizes the window, the form is populated dinamically from a SQL query, this is the constructor code:

```
procedure TForm2.MakeWindow;
var
  dummyMaskedit, dummyEdit: TEdit;
  dummyMemo: TMemo;
  dummyCombobox: TComboBox;
  dummyLabel: TLabel;
  dummyLBox: TListBox;
  dummybutton: TButton;
  i, f: integer;
  buffer, workarea: double;
begin
  FDQDB.Close;
  FDQDB.Open('SELECT * FROM Defs WHERE active = 1');

  i := 0;
  f := 1;
  buffer := Layout1.Width;
  workarea := Layout1.Width;
  SetLength(aMasks, 0);
  while not FDQDB.Eof do
  begin
    case AnsiIndexStr(FDQDB.FieldByName('comptype').AsString,
      ['tedit', 'tcombobox', 'tmaskedit', 'tlistbox']) of
      0: // TEdit
        begin
          dummyEdit := TEdit.Create(self);
          dummyEdit.Parent := Form2.Layout1;
          dummyEdit.Width := FDQDB.FieldByName('size').AsInteger;
          if buffer - dummyEdit.Width >= 0 then
          begin
            buffer := buffer - dummyEdit.Width - 8;
            dummyEdit.Position.Y := Panel2.Position.Y + 22 + (45 * i);
            dummyEdit.Position.X := workarea - buffer - dummyEdit.Width + 5;
          end
          else
          begin
            inc(i);
            buffer := workarea;
            buffer := buffer - dummyEdit.Width - 8;
            dummyEdit.Position.Y := Panel2.Position.Y + 22 + (45 * i);
            dummyEdit.Position.X := workarea - buffer - dummyEdit.Width + 5;
          end;
          dummyEdit.Name := 'field' + IntToStr(f);
          inc(f);

          dummyLabel := TLabel.Create(self);
          with dummyLabel do
          begin
            Parent := dummyEdit.Parent;
            Text := FDQDB.FieldByName('Descricao').AsString;
            Position.Y := dummyEdit.Position.Y - 17;
            Position.X := dummyEdit.Position.X;
          end;
        end;

      1: // TComboBox
        begin
          dummyCombobox := TComboBox.Create(self);
          dummyCombobox.Parent := Form2.Layout1;
          dummyCombobox.Width := FDQDB.FieldByName('size').AsInteger;
          if buffer - dummyCombobox.Width >= 0 then
          begin
            buffer := buffer - dummyCombobox.Width - 8;
            dummyCombobox.Position.Y := Panel2.Position.Y + 22 + (45 * i);
            dummyCombobox.Position.X := workarea - buffer -
              dummyCombobox.Width + 5;
          end
          else
          begin
            inc(i);
            buffer := workarea;
            buffer := buffer - dummyCombobox.Width - 8;
            dummyCombobox.Position.Y := Panel2.Position.Y + 22 + (45 * i);
            dummyCombobox.Position.X := workarea - buffer -
              dummyCombobox.Width + 5;
          end;
          dummyCombobox.Name := 'field' + IntToStr(f);
          dummyCombobox.Items.Delimiter := '|';
          dummyCombobox.Items.StrictDelimiter := true;
          dummyCombobox.Items.DelimitedText :=
            AnsiUpperCase(FDQDB.FieldByName('combovalue').AsString);
          inc(f);

          dummyLabel := TLabel.Create(self);
          with dummyLabel do
          begin
            Parent := dummyCombobox.Parent;
            Text := FDQDB.FieldByName('Descricao').AsString;
            Position.Y := dummyCombobox.Position.Y - 17;
            Position.X := dummyCombobox.Position.X;
          end;
        end;

      2: // TMaskEdit
        begin
          dummyMaskedit := TEdit.Create(self);
          dummyMaskedit.Parent := Form2.Layout1;
          dummyMaskedit.Width := FDQDB.FieldByName('size').AsInteger;
          if buffer - dummyMaskedit.Width >= 0 then
          begin
            buffer := buffer - dummyMaskedit.Width - 8;
            dummyMaskedit.Position.Y := Panel2.Position.Y + 22 + (45 * i);
            dummyMaskedit.Position.X := workarea - buffer -
              dummyMaskedit.Width + 5;
          end
          else
          begin
            inc(i);
            buffer := workarea;
            buffer := buffer - dummyMaskedit.Width - 8;
            dummyMaskedit.Position.Y := Panel2.Position.Y + 22 + (45 * i);
            dummyMaskedit.Position.X := workarea - buffer -
              dummyMaskedit.Width + 5;
          end;
          dummyMaskedit.Name := 'field' + IntToStr(f);
          inc(f);

          SetLength(aMasks, length(aMasks) + 1);
          Masks.field := dummyMaskedit.Name;
          Masks.mask := FDQDB.FieldByName('mask').AsString;
          aMasks[length(aMasks) - 1] := Masks;

          dummyMaskedit.OnExit := MaskTextExit;

          dummyLabel := TLabel.Create(self);
          with dummyLabel do
          begin
            Parent := dummyMaskedit.Parent;
            Text := FDQDB.FieldByName('Descricao').AsString;
            Position.Y := dummyMaskedit.Position.Y - 17;
            Position.X := dummyMaskedit.Position.X;
          end;
        end;

      3: // TListBox
        begin
          dummyLBox := TListBox.Create(self);
          dummyLBox.Parent := Form2.Layout1;
          dummyLBox.Width := FDQDB.FieldByName('size').AsInteger;
          inc(i);
          buffer := workarea;
          if buffer - dummyLBox.Width >= 0 then
          begin
            buffer := buffer - dummyLBox.Width - 8;
            dummyLBox.Position.Y := Panel2.Position.Y + 22 + (45 * i);
            dummyLBox.Position.X := workarea - buffer - dummyLBox.Width + 5;
          end
          else
          begin
            inc(i);
            buffer := workarea;
            buffer := buffer - dummyLBox.Width - 8;
            dummyLBox.Position.Y := Panel2.Position.Y + 22 + (45 * i);
            dummyLBox.Position.X := workarea - buffer - dummyLBox.Width + 5;
          end;
          dummyLBox.Name := 'field' + IntToStr(f);
          inc(f);

          SetLength(aMasks, length(aMasks) + 1);
          Masks.field := dummyLBox.Name;
          Masks.mask := FDQDB.FieldByName('mask').AsString;
          aMasks[length(aMasks) - 1] := Masks;

          dummyLabel := TLabel.Create(self);
          with dummyLabel do
          begin
            Parent := dummyLBox.Parent;
            Text := FDQDB.FieldByName('Descricao').AsString;
            Position.Y := dummyLBox.Position.Y - 17;
            Position.X := dummyLBox.Position.X;
          end;

          dummybutton := TButton.Create(self);
          with dummybutton do
          begin
            Parent := dummyLBox.Parent;
            Text := '+';
            Width := 20;
            Position.X := dummyLBox.Width + dummyLBox.Position.X + 3;
            Position.Y := dummyLBox.Position.Y;
            Name := 'ba' + dummyLBox.Name;
            OnClick := ButtonsAddClick;
          end;

          dummybutton := TButton.Create(self);
          with dummybutton do
          begin
            Parent := dummyLBox.Parent;
            Text := '-';
            Width := 20;
            Position.X := dummyLBox.Width + dummyLBox.Position.X + 3;
            Position.Y := dummyLBox.Position.Y + 28;
            Name := 'br' + dummyLBox.Name;
            OnClick := ButtonsRemClick;
          end;
        end;
    end;
    FDQDB.Next;
  end;
  FDQDB.Close;
end;
```

That works nice and pretty on the windowed state of the application, this code is applied to the onCreate event of the form:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDCDB.Params.Database := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'window.db';
  MakeWindow;
end;
```

The first form, main form of the application, is the one that summons the new form that has the components built in runtime:

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Form2.Layout1.parent := Self.Layout1.Parent;
  Form2.Layout1.Width := Self.Layout1.Width;
end;
```

The second form has a TLayout, just like the first form. Then, when I create the form I bring the TLayout of the second form to the first. So far so good, it works when the application is launched in windowed mode.
But when I put form1 in fullscreen mode, then click the Button that creates the form2, the components stays on the same position as in windowed mode. I've tried changing the workarea variable to these:

```
Screen.width, //components behave as the application were in fullscreen the whole time
Screen.WorkAreaWidth, //same as screen.width
(Layout1.Parent as TLayout).Width, //invalid typecast
(Layout1.GetParentComponent as TLayout).Width //invalid typecast
```

None of them worked.
I wanna be able to adjust the position of the components on the screen based on its visual width, so if the user resizes the window before creating the new form, the components gets aligned properly.
Anyone knows a solution for that? Thanks in advance

Comment: The `OnResize` of the form is one place to do resizing of the contained controls.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `FMX.Controls.TControl.Realign` method after assigning new parent (or after window resizing). From docs: **The children are realigned taking into account their alignment properties, margins, and padding.**.

Comment: ok, but I can't just redo the whole window every time the user resizes the canvas, I will adjust the components on the creation event and then if the user resizes the window for any particular reason he would just need to close the opened forms and reopen them, main form components won't be touched, only children forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I put form1 in fullscreen mode, then click the Button that
>   creates the form2, the components stays on the same position as in
>   windowed mode.

At `TForm1.SpeedButton1Click()` you call `Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);` which triggers `TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);` which calls `MakeWindow`. At this point `Form2` knows only about the design time size.

After `MakeWindow` is done, the `TForm1.SpeedButton1Click()` continues:

```
Form2.Layout1.parent := Self.Layout1.Parent;
Form2.Layout1.Width := Self.Layout1.Width;
```

but these do not anymore affect the layout of the controls.

You need to set `Form2.Layout1.Width` before you call `MakeWindow`, for example:

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Form2.Layout1.parent := Self.Layout1.Parent;
  Form2.Layout1.Width := Self.Layout1.Width;
  MakeWindow; // remove it from TForm2.FormCreate()
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The form has ClientWidth and ClientHeight properties which work well in OnResize to dynamically size a control based on the area available. The OnResize fires before the form is made visible. For example to have a Memo1 with a 100 border around it:

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  memo1.Position.X := 100;  // Only needs to be done once but here so all code is in one spot
  memo1.Position.Y := 100;
  memo1.Width := form1.ClientWidth - 200;
  memo1.Height := form1.ClientHeight - 200;
end;
```

Comment: The form isn't being visible, I'm not firing the onShow event on it. Also I put my MakeWindow procedure on the onResize event, the components still appears on the same spot as the windowed application.

Comment: Make the child once. In the child's OnResize setup the size of things.